# Plotting a grouped stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a grouped, stacked bar chart. I was able to do it in excel and this image shows what I am trying to create but I want to do it through Python. I have all the data in a pandas data frame that is able to create separate stacked bar charts but I cannot get the grouping as seen in excel.

Excel Formatting:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far and what is your problem exactly? I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you could do it in Excel with easy then I strongly suggest you to do it with Excel. Unless you have other requirements.

There are many libraries you can use to create this type of plot: `matplotlib`, `seaborn`, or `plotly`. The one I use most is `plotly`. You can see the list of sample figures of `plotly` here: https://plotly.com/python/

Or you can join `plotly` community, there are many pros there might help with figure. I find there is few pros on figures in stackoverflow to plotly community: https://community.plotly.com/